# Tomcat is not started with docker compose

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to start tomcat with the help of docker compose file  but tomcat is not started with docker compose. My docker-machine ip is 192.168.99.100. I can't access server with `http://192.168.99.100:8080`. I am docker beginner and trying to start tomcat and deploy any app using docker. Any help much appreciated

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

    services:
      tomcat:
        image: tomcat:8.5.35
        container_name: tomcat
        volumes:
          - ./docker/myapp.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myapp.war
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
```

**Stack trace :**

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating dockercompose_tomcat_1 ... done
Attaching to dockercompose_tomcat_1
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.448 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.50
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.569 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Dec 7 2019 19:19:46 UTC
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.574 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 8.5.50.0
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.576 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.578 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.14.134-boot2docker
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.580 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.584 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/local/openjdk-8/jre
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.586 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_232-b09
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.588 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.591 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /usr/local/tomcat
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.593 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /usr/local/tomcat
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.596 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/u
sr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.599 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.ap
ache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.602 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.603 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.a
pache.catalina.webresources
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.605 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.Sec
urityListener.UMASK=0027
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.608 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.610 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.611 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.617 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Ver
sionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat
/temp
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.619 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLif
ecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2
.23] using APR version [1.5.2].
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.619 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLif
ecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], ac
cept filters [false], random [true].
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.629 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLif
ecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false]
, useOpenSSL [true]
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:52.797 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLif
ecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.0l  1
0 Sep 2019]
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:54.398 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProto
col.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:54.597 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioS
electorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:54.666 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProto
col.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:54.676 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioS
electorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:54.679 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Cat
alina.load Initialization processed in 6577 ms
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:54.970 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.Standa
rdService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:54.970 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.Standa
rdEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.50
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:55.170 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cat
alina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/u
sr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:56.746 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.
catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom
 instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [234] milliseconds.
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:56.890 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cat
alina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory
 [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [1,717] ms
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:56.891 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cat
alina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/u
sr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs]
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:56.967 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cat
alina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory
 [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/docs] has finished in [76] ms
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:56.967 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cat
alina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/u
sr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager]
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:57.132 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cat
alina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory
 [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager] has finished in [165] ms
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:57.134 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cat
alina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/u
sr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager]
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:57.242 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cat
alina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory
 [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/manager] has finished in [109] ms
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:57.243 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cat
alina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/u
sr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples]
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:58.803 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cat
alina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory
 [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/examples] has finished in [1,561] ms
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:58.814 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProto
col.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
tomcat_1  | 03-Jan-2020 21:37:58.852 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProto
col.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]Dio
col.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Comment: So you are trying to start tomcat on one machine, and then access it from another? If yes, have you tried login into machine where tomcat should start and open localhost:8080/myapp? According to logs tomcat did start, myapp was not yet deployed. You may not be able to access it due to some networking issues between machines.

Comment: everything is local. also ,would you kind enough to let me know how I can deploy webapp using docker compose as I am beginner and have limited knowledge

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that everything is local, try http://localhost:8080/myapp instead via IP.

Also, looks like you’re referencing your myapp.war in a relative way. Relative to docker-compose.yml, not to location you run docker-compose command from. I suggest you try full path instead (just to test it).

Lastly If you don’t plan to add more services to that docker compose, I’d switch to Dockerfile instead. Then you can easily build new image with embedded myapp.war and run it wherever you’d like.